# Compose not refreshing view on change of mutableStateOf value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel with the property

`var uiState by mutableStateOf(UiState())`

I have a composable that accesses this value like so

```
fun AppView(viewModel: BridgeViewModel) {
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState

    when {
        uiState.isLoading -> {
            LoadingView()
        }
        uiState.data != null -> {
            TextToShareView(to = uiState.data)
        }
    }
}
```

After the composable is created I trigger a function in my ViewModel that changes the state like so

`uiState = UiState(isLoading = true)`

The problem is, the composable is not being redrawn when I change the value of state.

Any idea? I can't see how this is different to the official sample in the docs.

Comment: state should be declared as `mutableStateOf(State())`, you can use it with delegation. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmv2ug-wW4U) for details

Comment: @PylypDukhov I've edited my question as I think me naming a property state caused some confusion? I am using mutableStateOf not stateOf function.

Comment: I see, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)